# Laravel Query Error - Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::query()

Tags: php, mysql, csv, laravel-5, import-from-excel

Id like to insert some data from a CSV file but when i upload them has a error report.
Whats the best way to do that in laravel or PHP.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsrKC.png)

```
public function uploadFile(Request $request){

  $conexao = \DB::table('tb_pwbi_analytics_acesso');

  $arquivo = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
  $nome = $_FILES['file']['name'];

  $ext = explode(".", $nome);
  $extensao = end($ext);

  if ($extensao != 'csv') {
    echo 'extenso invalida';

  }else{
    $objeto =fopen($arquivo, 'r');       
    while (($dados = fgetcsv($objeto,1000,";")) !== FALSE) {
    $regional = utf8_encode($dados[0]);
    $uf = utf8_encode($dados[1]);
    $anf = utf8_encode($dados[2]);
    $localidade = utf8_encode($dados[3]);
    $ibge = utf8_encode($dados[4]);
    $ativo = utf8_encode($dados[5]);


    $result = $conexao->query("INSERT INTO tb_pwbi_analytics_acesso (regional, uf, anf, localidade, ibge, ativo) VALUES('$regional',' $uf','$anf','$localidade', '$ibge','$ativo')");

   }if($result){
    echo 'Dados inseridos com sucesso!';
   }else{
    echo 'Erro ao inserir os dados';
   }
}
```

Comment: add use DB; and then try with DB::table not \DB

Answer (score 1):

The method `query()` is not from a builder instance. It is in `Illuminate\Database\Connection` class. Use the DB facade (`use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;`) to insert the information you desire.

```
DB::table('tb_pwbi_analytics_acesso')->insert(
    [
    'regional' => $regional,
    'uf' => $uf,
    // and so on
    ]
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Query Builder, but the form that was placed is wrong. The correct way to insert new records according to the documentation

```
$attributes = [
     'name'   =>   'Name X'
     'email'  =>   'email@x.com'
]
$insert = \DB::table('tb_pwbi_analytics_acesso')->create($attributes);

dd($insert)
```